# Function to check if folder path is valid

Tags: c, file-system, windows

It is a function that validates a string is a correct windows path to a directory.
It returns negative numbers if it isn't, 0 if it is correct and 1 if it also exists:

```
int path_is_correct_directory (char *path)
{
    size_t  szPath          = 0U;

    if(path == NULL)
        return -1;
    if(*path == '\0')
        return -2;

    szPath = strlen(path);

    if(szPath < 3 || szPath > MAX_PATH)
        return -3;

    char    driveLetter[3]      = { path[0], path[1], '\0' };
    BOOL    validDriveLetter    = PathIsDirectory(driveLetter);

    if(validDriveLetter == 0)
        return -4;

    if(path[2] != '\\')
        return -5;

    int i;
    for(i = 3; i < szPath; i++)
    {
        if(path[i] == '/')  return -6;
        if(path[i] == ':')  return -7;
        if(path[i] == '*')  return -8;
        if(path[i] == '"')  return -9;
        if(path[i] == '<')  return -10;
        if(path[i] == '>')  return -11;
        if(path[i] == '|')  return -12;
        if(path[i] == '?')  return -13;
    }

    if(PathIsDirectory(path))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have access to `Dir`?

Comment: @Raystafarian what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

## Magic numbers

All error codes are magic numbers. It's hard to keep numbers in mind, though. If I use

```
path_is_correct_directory(some_path)
```

and get `-6`, what exactly did I do wrong? I have to look into the documentation, check the error values and add that to my own code:

```
if(path_is_correct_directory(some_path) == -6) {
    yell_at_user("Path may not contain slash!");
}
```

But that's still opaque. Instead, use an `enum`:

```
enum RESULTS {
    PATH_IS_VALID     = 0,
    PATH_IS_DIRECTORY = 1,
    /*   ---   */
    PATH_IS_NULL   = -1,
    PATH_IS_EMPTY  = -2,
    PATH_TOO_SHORT = -3,
    /*   ---   */
    INVALID_DRIVE           = -4,
    INVALID_DRIVE_DELIMITER = -5,
    /*   ---   */
    PATH_CONTAINS_SLASH         = -6,
    PATH_CONTAINS_COLON         = -7,
    PATH_CONTAINS_ASTERISK      = -8,
    PATH_CONTAINS_QUOTE         = -9,
    PATH_CONTAINS_LT            = -10,
    PATH_CONTAINS_GT            = -11,
    PATH_CONTAINS_PIPE          = -12,
    PATH_CONTAINS_QUESTION_MARK = -13
};
```

Instead of magic numbers, I can now confidently compare against a nice name:

```
if(path_is_correc_directory(some_path) == PATH_IS_DIRECTORY) {
    list_directory_contents(some_path);
}
```

## Keep scope of variables short

Since you use C99, you can keep the scope of your variables shorter. For example `i` should only be valid *in* the `for` loop, but not outside. `szPath` can get initialized with `strlen` right away (after the `NULL` check).

## Variables that shouldn't change can be `const`

All `szPath`, `path` `driveLetter` and `validDriveLetter` should not change and can therefore get changed to `const`.

## `sz` is a prefix for strings, not numbers

In Hungarian notation `sz` is a prefix for "**s**tring terminated by **z**ero". Since Hungarian notation is used throughout Windows APIs, that can be a source of confusion. `path_size` is fine on the other hand.

## All at once

```
int path_is_correct_directory (const char *path)
{
    if(path == NULL)
        return PATH_IS_NULL;
    if(*path == '\0')
        return PATH_IS_EMPTY;

    const size_t path_size = strlen(path);

    if(path_size < 3 || path_size> MAX_PATH)
        return PATH_TOO_SHORT;

    const char    driveLetter[3]      = { path[0], path[1], '\0' };
    const BOOL    validDriveLetter    = PathIsDirectory(driveLetter);

    if(validDriveLetter == 0)
        return INVALID_DRIVE;

    if(path[2] != '\\')
        return INVALID_DRIVE_DELIMITER;

    for(int i = 3; i < path_size; i++)
    {
        if(path[i] == '/')  return PATH_CONTAINS_SLASH;
        if(path[i] == ':')  return PATH_CONTAINS_COLON;
        if(path[i] == '*')  return PATH_CONTAINS_ASTERISK;
        if(path[i] == '"')  return PATH_CONTAINS_QUOTE;
        if(path[i] == '<')  return PATH_CONTAINS_LT;
        if(path[i] == '>')  return PATH_CONTAINS_GT;
        if(path[i] == '|')  return PATH_CONTAINS_PIPE;
        if(path[i] == '?')  return PATH_CONTAINS_QUESTION_MARK;
    }

    if(PathIsDirectory(path))
        return PATH_IS_DIRECTORY;

    return PATH_IS_VALID;
}
```

By the way, Windows also supports network directories, which start with `\\`.

Comment: To handle network directory he can rely on `PathIsUNCA` from the same header than `PathIsDirectory`.